# MNIST and SGDClassifier classifer

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, mnist

I'm trying to use online([out-of-core)](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_out_of_core_classification.html#) learning algorithm for MNIST problem using [SGDClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html)
But it seems that accuracy not always increasing.

What should I do in this case? save somehow classifer with best accuracy? 
Is SGDClassifier converging to some optimal solution?

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model.stochastic_gradient import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

#use all digits
mnist = fetch_mldata("MNIST original")
X_train, y_train = mnist.data[:70000] / 255., mnist.target[:70000]

X_train, y_train = shuffle(X_train, y_train)
X_test, y_test = X_train[60000:70000], y_train[60000:70000]  

step =1000
batches= np.arange(0,60000,step)
all_classes = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
classifier = SGDClassifier()
for curr in batches:
 X_curr, y_curr = X_train[curr:curr+step], y_train[curr:curr+step]
 classifier.partial_fit(X_curr, y_curr, classes=all_classes)
 score= classifier.score(X_test, y_test)
 print score

print "all done"
```

I tested linearSVM vs SGD on MNIST using 10k samples for train and 10k for test and get 0.883 13,95 and 0.85 1,32 so SGD faster but less accurate.

```
#test linearSVM vs SGD
t0 = time.time()
clf = LinearSVC()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
score= clf.score(X_test, y_test)
print score
print (time.time()-t0)

t1 = time.time()
clf = SGDClassifier()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
score= clf.score(X_test, y_test)
print score
print (time.time()-t1)
```

also I found some info here 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/14936/16843

**UPDATE:**  more then one pass (10 passes) through the data achived best accuracy 90.8 %.So it can be solution. And another specificity of SGD that data must be shuffled before passed to classifier.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to add the output of your script so that people who don't have sklearn installed handy can still follow the question? What you observe and what you would have expected to happen instead?

Comment: Score's output something like 0.52 0.6 0.75 0.74 0.84 0.80 0.82 at begining it increasing but then it fluctuating about 0.8+-some_value and I expect that it will be always increasing to some max_score value and then stops.

Comment: You can find an already decoded version of the MNIST dataset here: http://mnist-decoded.000webhostapp.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First remark: you are using `SGDClassifier` with the default parameters: they are likely not the optimal values for this dataset: try other values as well (especially for alpha, the regularization parameter).

Now to answer your question it's quite unlikely that a linear model will do very good on a dataset like MNIST which is digit image classification task. You might want to try linear models such as:

- `SVC(kernel='rbf')` (but not scalable, try on a small subset of the training set) and not incremental / out-of-core
- `ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimator=100)` or more but not out-of-core either. The larger the number of sub estimators, the longer it will take to train.

You can also try the [Nystroem approximation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/kernel_approximation.html#nystroem-kernel-approx) of `SVC(kernel='rbf')` by transforming the dataset using a `Nystroem(n_components=1000, gamma=0.05)` fitted on a small subset of the data (e.g. 10000 samples) and then passing the whole transformed training set to a linear model such as `SGDClassifier`: it requires 2 passes over the dataset.

There is also a [pull request for 1 hidden layer perceptron](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/2120) on github that should be both faster to to compute than `ExtraTreesClassifier` and approach 98% test set accuracy on MNIST (and also provide a partial_fit API for out-of-core learning).

**Edit**: the fluctuation of the estimate of the `SGDClassifier` score is expected: SGD stands for stochastic gradient descent, which means that examples are considered one at a time: badly classified samples can cause an update of the weights of the model in a way that is detrimental for other samples, you need to do more than one pass over the data to make the learning rate decrease enough to get a smoother estimate of the validation accuracy. You can use [itertools.repeat](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) in your for loop to do several passes (e.g. 10) over your dataset.

Comment: Thank's for answer but I need online(out-of-core) algorithm, I'm just trying it on MNIST. Is SGDClassifier converging to some optimal solution?

Comment: Yes but only when you have enough samples and your task is linearly separable.

Comment: Is partial_fit used just for Big Data?(when we can't fit all samples into memory).   
Whether there can be such situation when we have almost unlimited data, but when we feed data with partial_fit we get some accuracy(for example 80%) but we don't know when to stop because of fluctuations of classifer(is it always better to process all available data?) So what is advantage over other linear classifers(is it faster or more precise)?(maybe for big data we can train N linear classifers on small batches of data and linear regression on top of this instead ?)

Comment: I tested linearSVM vs SGD on MNIST and get 0.883 13,95 and 0.85 1,32 so SGD faster but less accurate.

Comment: Have you grid searched the optimal value for C (for LinearSVM) and alpha and n_iter (for SGDClassifier)? There are also other hyper-parameters that can be tuned for each of them but their impact is probably less important than the aforementioned parameters.

Comment: "Is partial_fit used just for Big Data?" yes, it's just for out-of-core learning. But the presence of the `partial_fit` method on a model actually describes that the underlying training procedure supports incremental learning. Not all models can provide a `partial_fit` method because some models need to have access to all the samples ahead of time to be able to adjust their internal parameters in batch.

Comment: The fact that the validation accuracy curve that you get when calling `partial_fit` iteratively is non smooth is caused by the underlying training algorithm, in this case vanilla SGD. `MultinomialNB` also supports incremental learning with `partial_fit` and will probably be much smoother. If we implement Averaged SGD one day, the accuracy curve should also be smoother.